# Compose collectAsState from a StateFlow not recomposing the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I have a `StateFlow` screen state in the `ViewModel` which I'm trying to propagate to a `Composable` screen through a `Fragment`. In some cases, the screen is not being recomposed even when the state changes.
I know for sure that the value of the screen state is changing because I'm able to collect it in the fragment using `viewModel.screenState.collectLatest`.

ViewModel.kt

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val someData1 = MutableStateFlow("initialData1")
    private val someData2 = MutableStateFlow("initialData2")
    val screenState: StateFlow<ScreenState> = combine(someData1, someData2) { data1, data2 ->
        // ScreenState is a data class
        ScreenState(data1, data2)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = ScreenState("initialData1", "initialData2"),
    )
}
```

MyFragment.kt

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = ComposeView(inflater.context).apply {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.screenState.collectLatest {
                Log.d(TAG, "new state is always collected here successfully")
            }
        }
        setContent {
            val screenState by viewModel.screenState.collectAsState()
            // SOMETIMES NOT RECOMPOSING!!!
            MyScreen(
                screenState = screenState,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

MyScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    screenState: ScreenState,
) {
    Log.d(TAG, "screen not recomposing on state change") // this line not called!
}
```

Replacing `collectAsState` with `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` didn't help.

Using `androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.06.01`.

Comment: I faced that issue as well. Try removing the Fragment, and test it without the Fragment and then it will surely work. Also, you better use the `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` extension function from now on.

Comment: Removing the `Fragment` is a very big refactor of the entire application so I prefer to avoid it right now. None of the other screens seem to share this problem.
As mentioned in the question "Replacing collectAsState with collectAsStateWithLifecycle didn't help.".

Answer (score 0):

Here, You are using fragment that will not recompose every time, for that you have to use @Composable (it will recompose every time it notices any changes in data)

I think use of fragments in compose is bad habit. You should use compose navigation graph with different composable screens.

you can refer this link for compose navigation
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/navigating-in-jetpack-compose-78c78d365c6a

Comment: I forgot to put the `@Composable` annotation in the question but it's there in the original code (added in edit). The screen does recompose MOST of the times the `StateFlow` changes but not ALL the times. I'm trying to figure out what may be causing it to skip some changes while reacting to others. The `Fragment` unfortunately is a given at this point because it's not my code originally.